# window.onunload is not working in Samsung Galaxy Tab browser

Tags: javascript, android, jquery, dom-events

In my application clicking on a link a child window opens, now when I close the parent window I need to capture `window.onunload` event of parent window so that I can close child window.

This is working fine in desktop browsers, but not in Samsung Galaxy Tab in built browser.

Can anybody help me on that?

Comment: onunload is not reliable anyways.

Comment: So, can you please give me a suggestion how to handle this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Due to inconsistencies in browser support, you might consider redundant mechanisms using a shotgun approach:

- Trap the parent window's hide, unload, and beforeunload events and close the child window.  Trap ALL of them!  One of them is bound to work.
- Write a timer in the child window that polls/checks for window.opener and closes itself if the parent no longer exists

Answer (score 0):

You need to check if window.unload is even supported on that browser. You might want to look at using div overlays instead which you can control.

Comment: Do you know samsung tablet browser supports window.unload or not?

Comment: I don't. I couldn't find any docs for it. I don't have one, but best way is to try it in the browser. Have you seen the desired behavior on a different site on your desktop? Now, try that same site on the tablet and see if it works... ?

Answer (score -1):

The onbeforeunload function isn't implemented by H browser, instead use:

window.onHide callback function